# ThreeJS Image Transition by Switching Planes and Rotating Camera Angle

Tags: image, camera, transition, plane

Does anyone know how to do 2d image transitions through switching planes by rotating the camera angle?  I have been experimenting with the skybox model as follows:

```
const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
const texture = loader.load([
  'image1.jpg',
  'image2.jpg',
  'image3.jpg',
  'image4.jpg',
  'image5.jpg',
  'image6.jpg',
]);
scene.background = texture;
```

However, I want the camera to zoom in a little bit first before the camera rotation so that it looks as though the 2D image is 3D.  A good example of this would be https://travelshift.com, where the user can even control the camera by holding the mouse button, even though the camera angle still stays exactly at the centre of the page.

I have also tried searching for image distortion to see if I can achieve a similar effect.  But after creating several image distortion animations, I realised that I could not come anywhere as close because of a lack of a camera perspective in JQuery.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make 2d images look 3d as they transition to another image?  Any help would be appreciated.